# A problem with pagination codeigniter (page 2 not showing)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

im getting stuck when i show data from database with pagination codeigniter, the first page is show correctly, but when i click page 2, the number of page is selected but its still show the data of page 1, so do with next page. Here is my code

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$perpage = 5;
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/contname/method/'.$id;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->feedbackmodel->count_itemscat($id);
$config['per_page'] = $perpage;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Anyone help me please
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks fine. We need to see your database query too.

Comment: its about uri segment, i have fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your model how are you getting the page data. You must set the page you are looking for in that function, like in

```
    function getPage($count = 5, $from = 0) { // params are important
    $this->db->select('*', FALSE);

    ..........

    $query = $this->db->get('your_table', $count, $from); // <- that's important: $count, $from

    return $query->result();
}
```

it sounds like you are missing the 'from' param or something like that

Comment: i have fixed with add this in controller :  $offset = $this->uri->segment(4). Thanks!

Comment: Great! I suspected that the offset problem was in the model, not in the controller.

Comment: sorry, I have not opened stackoverflow for a long time, now i have accepted the answer, thanks :)